# filter dataframe with multiple conditions name matching in R dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

```
type sex eth  a_t a_tm b_tm c_tm d_tm e_tm 
1    m   a    0      0    0    1    1    0
0    f   b    1      1    0    0    1    1
0    m   a    0      0    0    1    1    1
1    f   a    1      1    1    1    0    0
0    f   c    1      0    0    1    0    1
```

How can I select columns using `dplyr` where the column ends with `_tm` or the column is in a list containing `sex` or `eth`?

expected output

```
sex eth  a_tm b_tm c_tm d_tm e_tm 
m   a    0    0    1    1    0
f   b    1    0    0    1    1
m   a    0    0    1    1    1
f   a    1    1    1    0    0
f   c    0    0    1    0    1
```

I want to do this in `dplyr` without using `grepl`... is this possible?

Comment: Then use `grep()` instead. It satisfies your condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using `select-helpers` - `ends_with` in `select`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    select(sex, eth, ends_with('_tm'))
```

-output

```
   sex eth a_tm b_tm c_tm d_tm e_tm
1   m   a    0    0    1    1    0
2   f   b    1    0    0    1    1
3   m   a    0    0    1    1    1
4   f   a    1    1    1    0    0
5   f   c    0    0    1    0    1
```

---

Other options include `matches("_tm$")` in place of `ends_with`  i.e. if we use `regex`, it can be done all in `matches` - `matches("^(sex|eth)$|_tm$")` where the we use the pattern to match the 'sex' or (`|`) 'eth' from the start (`^`) till the end (`$`) of the string or (`|`) the substring '_tm' at the end (`$`) of the string in column names

```
df1 %>%
    select(matches("^(sex|eth)$|_tm$"))
  sex eth a_tm b_tm c_tm d_tm e_tm
1   m   a    0    0    1    1    0
2   f   b    1    0    0    1    1
3   m   a    0    0    1    1    1
4   f   a    1    1    1    0    0
5   f   c    0    0    1    0    1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(type = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L), sex = c("m", "f", 
"m", "f", "f"), eth = c("a", "b", "a", "a", "c"), a_t = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), a_tm = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L), b_tm = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L), c_tm = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), d_tm = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 0L), e_tm = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```